# Object references of model getting lost on view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm triying to implement a view where I pass it an object with certain references to other objects, edit some fields and get it back to persis, the problem is those references are coming back as null once i get the object back, heres my implementation:

this is the model i pass to the view:

```
public class TicketCreationModel
{


    public SupportItem item { get; set; }
    public Ticket ticket{ get; set; }
    public Employee employee{ get; set; }




}
```

pretty simple, the model has a ticket, a support item and an employee. Now heres the method where I pass my model to the view:

```
public ActionResult AssignSupportItem(int supportItemId)
    {

        Ticket ticket = GetTicket();
        ticket.Item = repo.GetSupportItemFromId(supportItemId);
        TicketCreationModel model = new TicketCreationModel();
        model.employee = ticket.AccountableEmployee;
        model.item = ticket.Item;
        model.ticket = ticket;
        return View(model);
    }
```

GetTicket() method on the first line returns the session object, here's the implementation:

```
private Ticket GetTicket()
    {
        Ticket ticket = (Ticket)Session["Ticket"];
        if (ticket == null)
        {
            ticket = new Ticket();
            Session["Ticket"] = ticket;
        }
        return ticket;
    }
```

Now heres the view that takes the model and enables some edit fields for the ticket:

```
@model WebUI.Controllers.TicketCreationModel


@{
ViewBag.Title = "AssignSupportItem";
}

<h2>AssignSupportItem</h2>
```

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Creación ticket</legend>

    <label>Descripción del problema</label>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ticket.Description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ticket.Description)
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ticket.TicketId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.item)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.employee)

    <label>Solución aportada</label>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ticket.Solution)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ticket.Solution)
    </div>

    <label>Estado</label>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ticket.Status)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ticket.Status)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}



@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And finally heres the method called by the form on the view which recieves the model object:

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AssignSupportItem(TicketCreationModel model)
        {

```
        Ticket final = model.ticket;
        final.Item = GetTicket().Item;
        final.AccountableEmployee = GetTicket().AccountableEmployee;

        repo.SaveTicket(final);
        ViewBag.Message = "Su ticket ha sido agregado al sistema";
        return View("AssignSupportItemResponse");

    }
```

**The problem is that the model object i receive has the employee and item attributes as null, why is this happenning? I'm sending those objects on my model why are they getting lost? I tried to restore them with the session object but as soon as I try to persis the object on my context class i get**

“An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker”

exception.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is actually fairly complex. Controller has no way of re-assembling the model you have from the submitted data. Try creating a view model that only contains "simple" properties (i.e. strings, int, etc.) that you actually need to display. When submitted, you'd have to get the employee and item from the store and then update their values.

Comment: I think that should work, but isn't there a way to reference the objects?

Comment: There is a disconnect between data that was sent to the view and the data that gets submitted. If you get the IDs back you can use them to reference the object from the store.

Comment: Yep that works, but while checking the hiddenfors on my view the value for employee is a serial one which might suggest that ef could pick that reference and recreate the object, at least thats what i thought, your solution works like a charm, thanks a lot! will mark it as answer asap